# Django getting "first_name" is invalid keyword argument for this function" TypeError when creating an instance of my model class

Tags: python, sql-server, django, model

Using Django 1.11 and django-pyodbc-azure latest version if it is relevant.

I am new to Django and have been following along the 1.11 tutorial without any issues until this, and I am incredibly confused.

Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, name='Last Name')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {} ({})'.format(self.last_name, self.first_name, self.id)


class Game(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, name='Players')

    def __str__(self):
        return ' vs. '.join(self.players)


class Round(models.Model):
    GIN = 'GI'
    UNDERCUT = 'UN'
    KNOCK = 'KN'
    ENDING_ACITONS = (
        (GIN, 'Gin'),
        (UNDERCUT, 'Undercut'),
        (KNOCK, 'Knock'),
    )

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='Parent Game')
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='Winning Player')
    points = models.IntegerField(name='Points Awarded')
    end = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ENDING_ACITONS)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} awarded {} points via {}'.format(self.winner, self.points, self.end.name)
```

Now when I run manage.py shell and type:

```
from game.models import *
bobby = Player(first_name='Bobby', last_name='Fisher')
```

I am met with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mteper\PycharmProjects\GinRummy\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'first_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, as, like I said earlier, I am new to Django and Python in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `name` argument that is causing problems. You should set [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) instead.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Last Name')
```

Comment: This fixed the problem! Thank you.

What was the name argument doing to cause an error?

Comment: It was changing the name of the field from `'first_name'` to `'First Name'`, therefore `Player(first_name='Bobby')` would no longer work.

Comment: Ahhhh, just checked my database and indeed the column name was 'First Name'.  Thank you!